# How to normalize model probability scores in a binary classifier?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, logistic-regression

I inherited this code from a previous Software Engineer at a job I just started.  He told me he inherited it from someone else.  The way the developer described it to me is that the code is supposed to calibrate the outputted probability scores in a binary classifier(in this case Logistic Regression) to be normally distributed around a score of 500.  Scores would be between 1 and 1000.

The code I have has comments and says that it is an implementation of a Generalized Logistic Calibration Curve, however I am not really understanding what it does and am looking for an easier way to accomplish what is being done.

Code:

`python`

```
class GenLogCalibration:
    """A Generalized Logistic Calibration curve, built to map input review
    rates (between 0 and 100%) to the appropriate output score.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize calibration parameters"""
        self.A = 1.038
        self.K = -0.042
        self.Q = 18.046
        self.B = 0.0069
        self.M = 100.76
        self.V = 1  #must be > 0.  Use 1 to make fn invertible
        self.min_score = 1
        self.max_score = 990

    def get_score(self, review_rate):
        """Return the score value for the input review_rate.  Should be in
        [0,1] range"""
        assert 0 <= review_rate <= 1
        score = ((self.B * self.M) - math.log((review_rate - self.K) /
                 (self.Q * (self.A - review_rate)))) / self.B
        # cap scores at desired min and max value
        if score > self.max_score: score = self.max_score
        if score < self.min_score: score = self.min_score
        # round score to nearest integral value
        return round(score)

    def get_review_rate(self, score):
        """Return the review rate that best corresponds to the given calibrated
        score"""
        if score > self.max_score: score = self.max_score
        if score < self.min_score: score = self.min_score
        return self.A + (self.K - self.A) / (1 +
               self.Q * math.exp(- self.B * (score - self.M)))**(1/self.V)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on where I can look to understand what is happening?

I have looked at calibration curve implementations in sci-kit learn and [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/calibration/plot_calibration_curve.html), but it doesn't seem to pertain to the particular problem at hand.

Comment: If you're using ski-kit or pandas or something else, please at least tag your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks i tagged it with scikit-learn.